# ActionStatus only affects a single PageBlockButton, not both

Tags: visualforce, rerender, commandbutton

While testing a page I was working on, I noticed something strange- the `apex:actionStatus` I had set up to prevent users from clicking save more than once was only working with the button that the user clicked, but not the other button on the page.

This second button is generated by Salesforce by the attribute `location="both"` in my `apex:pageBlockButtons` tag.

My assumption is that since my `actionStatus` is contained inside the `apex:pageBlockButtons` tag, that the status would be duplicated by the process which creates the second button, allowing both of the buttons to be affected by the same ajax process. The gif below shows that this is not the case.

[image: Two Save Buttons, only one of which displays "working" when clicked, when both should be displayed the same way]

What changes could I make to my markup to share this single `actionStatus` across two buttons?

---

Example page which replicates this behavior:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Edit" mode="edit" id="accountPanel">
                <apex:pageMessages />
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="asyncStatus">
                        <apex:facet name="stop">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="stop_panel">
                                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" rerender="accountPanel" status="asyncStatus" />
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:facet name="start">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="start_panel">
                                <apex:commandButton value="Working..." disabled="true" />
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionStatus>
                </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

By changing the generated `status` value of the `event` json generated by Salesforce, from `'status':'j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:bottom:asyncStatus'` to `'status':'j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:asyncStatus'`, I am able to get the top and bottoms panels in sync, but only when clicking the bottom button, and these changes are removed once the page rerenders. It looks like I'll need to modify a lot more of the generated mark-up to get this to work, but I'm still looking for anyone who might have noticed this before.

```
<input class="btn" id="j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:j_id29" name="j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:j_id29" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id1',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:j_id29','parameters':{'j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:j_id29':'j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:j_id29'} ,'status':'j_id0:j_id1:accountPanel:j_id28:bottom:asyncStatus'} );return false;" value="Save" type="button">
```

Comment: An easy work around to this is to have a js "onclick" function that disables all buttons. When re-rendered, those buttons are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add pageblock buttons like

`<apex:PageBlockButtons  location="top/bottom/both">`